# How can I get the pdf $p(1-p)^x$ from the Geometric distribution?

Tags: statistics

I'm doing a question regarding MLEs and the CRLB. The given pdf is $f(x;p)=p(1-p)^x $.  The professor gave us a hint that this is actually a geometric distribution and that using that would make the question much easier. However, I am having trouble figuring out how this is the case?

I know the geometric distribution as $p(1-p)^{x-1}$ but not sure what parameter $\rm GEO()$ makes this true? I also need to find $E(X)$ and $\rm Var(X)$ but can't seem to do it without the geometric distribution hint.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What range of $x$ are possible for your distribution? If it's $x=1,2,3,\ldots$, then you can let $Y=X-1$ in which case $Y$ is distributed as $p(1-p)^{y-1}$ i.e. geometric. (In practice, both $X$ and $Y$ get called the geometric distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution.)

Comment: What does the "question regarding MLEs and the CRLB" actually ask you to do? What does GEO() mean? Do you know what "pdf" means and how it might differ from "pmf" (probability mass function) which is more suitable for geometric random variables?  I am voting to close this question as being unclear.

Comment: @Semiclassical the range is $x=0, 1, ...$ I see. I will try that and see what I come up with thanks

Comment: @DilipSarwate I need to use that pdf to find the MLE of $p$, and the MLE of $θ=(1-p)/p$ and then find the "CRLB for variances of unbiased estimators of $θ$". So far I got the first two parts but stuck at the CRLB part as I'm not sure how to gain the expected value of $f(x;p)=p(1-p)^{x-1}$

Answer (score 2):

There are **two** distributions known as geometric.

$p~(1-p)^x~~[x\in\{0,\ldots\}]$ is the probability for $x$ *failures before* the first *success*.

$p~(1-p)^{x-1}~~[x\in\{1,\ldots\}]$ is the probability for $x$ *trials until* the first success.